# Unclassifiable statement at 1 Error

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, freeform

I am writing a code in Fortran90. I have the following code:

```
subroutine QualModel(CCS, TI, AIdex,t_max)
use Global
implicit none
DOUBLE PRECISION :: CCS, TI, AIdex
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(10) :: t_max

CCS = 0.0
TI = 0.0
AIdex = 0.0

CCS = &
24.36597157615 + &
(-6.56894015990892) * (ustrand * 60.0)
```

When I try to compile this I get the error at Line `CCS = &` of `Unclassifiable statement at 1.`

Can someone tell me how do I solve this? I went through other questions but most of them suggest paranthesis issue, but here there is no such issue.

Comment: What is your file suffix? Do you use free form or fixed form source? There are many (many!) similar questions around, have you looked at them? How does your exact command line for compiling look like?

Answer (score 1):

As Vladimir F points out on the comments, the file suffix is important in Fortran codes to tell the compiler how to interpret the code.

The code you posted misses some variable declarations (`ustrand`), uses a module (`Global`) that I don't have and misses an `end`. However, if I use the following code which is very similar to yours

```
subroutine QualModel(CCS, TI, AIdex,t_max)
implicit none
DOUBLE PRECISION :: CCS, TI, AIdex,ustrand
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(10) :: t_max

CCS = 0.0
TI = 0.0
AIdex = 0.0

CCS = &
24.36597157615 + &
(-6.56894015990892) * (ustrand * 60.0)
end
```

The compilation differs when using the `.f` / `.f90` suffixes as shown below. Note that if you have to stick to the `.f` suffix in your files, you can use the `-ffree-form` option for the `gfortran` compiler to tell it to accept this input.

```
$ gfortran --version | head -n 2
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ gfortran -c test.f90
$ gfortran -c test.f
test.f:1.1:
subroutine QualModel(CCS, TI, AIdex,t_max)
1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
test.f:1.1:

subroutine QualModel(CCS, TI, AIdex,t_max)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
test.f:2.1:
<... omitted remaining errors ...>

$ gfortran -c -ffree-form test.f
```

Comment: The problem is the error message is different. You are just guessing. ~It's up to you, but I normally try to get some information from the OP which makes it clear where the problem comes from.

Comment: A problem at the first character, on the first line, seems to indicate that @Harald nailed it.

Comment: The error message appears just before the <... omitted remaining errors ...> (although on a different line, the error on the line that OP pointed out was several lines below) but I agree with you that I should have requested further info to OP.

Comment: @Holmz yes it is very probable, that's why I asked the comments in the way I did. If it is the case then it should be closed as a duplicate instead of answering (IMHO).